# MPI_Pack: Invalid buffer pointer

Tags: c++, mpi

So, this is my task. I should read K - 1 triples in the main process (K - is the number of processes). The triple consists of two **integer** numbers and a **double** one. I have to use **MPI_Pack** and a collective operation to send this triples to the other processes. But when using **MPI_Pack** I get an error: *invalid buffer pointer*.
Here is my code:

```
int flag;
    MPI_Initialized(&flag);
    if (flag == 0)
        return;
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int* intbuf = new int[2];
    double doublebuf;
    byte* rbuf = new byte[(size - 1)*(2 * sizeof(int)+sizeof(double))];
    if (rank == 0) {
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i){
            pt >> intbuf[1] >> intbuf[2] >> doublebuf; //pt is from the special library and it's okay
            MPI_Pack(intbuf, 2, MPI_INT, rbuf, sizeof(int)* 2, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Pack(&doublebuf, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rbuf, sizeof(double), &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }

    MPI_Bcast(rbuf, sizeof(rbuf), MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank != 0){
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i){
            MPI_Unpack(rbuf, sizeof(int)* 2, &pos, intbuf, 2, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Unpack(rbuf, sizeof(double), &pos, &doublebuf, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            pt << intbuf[1] << intbuf[2] << doublebuf;
        }

    }
```

What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've just fixed my errors. The error was occured while packing the data: the 5th agrument of **MPI_Pack** does not mean how much data do you pack, it means the size of you buffer (in my case the buffer is *rbuf*), the 2nd argument of **MPI_Unpack** has the same semantics. 
Here is the fixed code. It works.

```
int* intbuf = new int[2];
    double doublebuf;
    int N = (size - 1)*(2 * sizeof(int)+sizeof(double));
    byte* rbuf = new byte[N];
    int pos = 0;
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i){
            pt >> intbuf[0] >> intbuf[1] >> doublebuf;
            MPI_Pack(intbuf, 2, MPI_INT, rbuf, N, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Pack(&doublebuf, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rbuf, N, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    MPI_Bcast(rbuf, N, MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank != 0){
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i){
            int* intbuf_out = new int[2];
            double doublebuf_out;
            MPI_Unpack(rbuf, N, &pos, intbuf_out, 2, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Unpack(rbuf, N, &pos, &doublebuf_out, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            pt << intbuf_out[0] << intbuf_out[1] << doublebuf_out;
            delete(intbuf_out);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The main issue comes from this line:

```
MPI_Bcast(rbuf, sizeof(rbuf), MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

More specifically, it comes from `sizeof(rdbuf)` which should be replaced by `pos`. Indeed, `sizeof(rdbuf)` is a `sizeof(byte*)` which depending on your OS will likely be either 4 or 8, but which will have nothing to do with the size of the data you try to transfer... This fixed, your code might "work".

However, this still has a lot of issues:

1. Your allocate your packing buffer with some sort of arbitrary size which makes very little sense. Normally, to know how much of memory you need to pack some data, you should use `MPI_Pack_size()`.
2. Why on earth do you wan to use `MPI_Pack()` in the first place? This function is a sort of legacy from PVM (ie. Parallel Virtual Machine) which was a message passing library pre-existing MPI. This function's purpose is to simplify the transition from PVM to MPI, but certainly not to be used for de-novo developments.

To address your problem, I would encourage you to either call 2 distinct `MPI_Bcast()`, one with your 2 integers and one with your double. This is very simple and straightforward.

Another (better if scalability matters) possibility would be to create a structure containing your ints and double and to create a matching MPI structured type using `MPI_Type_create_struct()`.

Good luck with your code anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer. I am kind of newbie to MPI. But there was a little bit different error (I've just answered my own question to explain it).

Comment: @O.Phillips The main error is in insisting on using MPI_Pack at all.